# How can I specify Simulator to be opened

Tags: ios, flutter

Currently, I have installed Xcode & Xcode Beta. When I type `open -a Simulator` on terminal, the system will bring up the **Beta Simulator** as default.

Anyone knows how to open the normal Simulator in terminal?

B.T.W, I know I can open Simulator in terminal with

`open -a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`

However, I'm playing with Flutter, the **Run** button on Android Studio would run `open -a Simulator` and open up the beta simulator then the simulator crashed ...

Answer (score 0):

Set your `xcode-select` path beforehand.

E.g. `xcode-select`

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
open $(xcode-select -p)/Applications/Simulator.app
```

Where `/Applications/Xcode.app` is the path to your non-beta installed Xcode version.

Comment: It doesn't work. For me `open -a Xcode` opens Xcode exactly (not beta), but `open -a Simulator` opens Beta Simulator

Comment: yes, it works. I've updated my description, is there any way to run with only `open -a Simulator`?